# How to access properties of generic base class's parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-community-toolkit

I have a common class `PopupDialog` which has properties such as `bool IsBackDismissEnabled`. This is used to denote whether pressing back button will dismiss the dialog.

I am using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit Popup for showing a popup dialog.

**Here's my PopupDialog.cs**

```cs
public class PopupDialog
{
    public bool IsBackDismissEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

**Here's my Dialog Implementation**

```cs
using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views;

[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ForgotPasswordDialog : Popup<PopupDialog>
{
    public ForgotPasswordDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // I want to access IsBackDismissEnabled here
        // something like base.IsBackDismissEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

I want to access `PopupDialog`'s `IsBackDismissEnabled` from the derived class of `Popup<PopupDialog>` how can it be done?

In short, I have a class which is specified as a parameter to a generic class. And that generic class is derived in a class from which I want to access properties of previous class that is specified as a parameter to the generic class.

Comment: "from the derived class of Popup<PopupDialog>" your class inherits from `Popup` and not from `PopupDialog`! This is a very different thing. If you post the declaration of `Popup` we could tell you more. Because the bool property lives inside the generic object that lives (maybe) inside `Popup`

Comment: Same comment.  You need to show "class Popup" code.

Comment: @MongZhu, @granadaCoder, `Popup` and `Popup<T>` is provided by **Xamarin** under **Community Toolkit** Package. We don't have source for that.

Comment: @MongZhu `Popup` [seem to be](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/popup) helper class that allow to return strongly typed result of given type T. If that is the type OP is using it is very confusing why they expect *result* of the dialog to somehow impact the behavior of the dialog. Some clarification from OP would be nice (like link to the `Popup` class used in this question).

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen anyone attempt to do what you are attempting. I'm not even sure it makes logical sense. Please explain what you are trying to do: **Why** do you want `PopupDialog` to be a `generic parameter`?

Consider making it a parameter on `Popup`'s constructor, and save it in a property or field:

```cs
public class Popup
{
    public Popup(ISomeInterface myParam)
    {
        this.MyParam = myParam;
    }

    public ISomeInterface MyParam;
}

public class ForgotPasswordDialog : Popup
{
    public ForgotPasswordDialog() : base(new PopupDialog())
    {
    }

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Access MyParam
        ... this.MyParam.IsBackDismissEnabled ...
    }
}

public interface ISomeInterface
{
    bool IsBackDismissEnabled { get; set; }
}

public class PopupDialog : ISomeInterface
{
    public bool IsBackDismissEnabled { get; set; }
    ...
}

/// Usage
var myVariable = new ForgotPasswordDialog();
... myVariable.MyParam.IsBackDismissEnabled ...
```

To be useful, you'll want to specify an `interface` or `base class` that `MyParam` has. Here I show `ISomeInterface`. This might instead be some base class of `PopupDialog`.

Comment: Methinks the OP is learning OOP anti-patterns the hard way - like we all did at some point :) (ugh... there was a brief time when I came up with my own base class for _everything_, sssshhhh)